# Retrofit and JSON - java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Tried researching but I've found no luck.

I'm using `Retrofit` to get `JSON` data here;  any ideas why this code is throwing a `java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`. How should I fix it?

```
            git.getPlaces1(KEY, new Callback<pojo>() {
                @Override
                public void success(pojo pojo, Response response) {
                    String jsonData = response.getBody().toString();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonData);

                    } catch(JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("jsonERROR", e.toString());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    Log.d("test2", error.toString());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why do you need to parse anything yourself? You've been given a `pojo` object already

Comment: didn't you add GsonConverterFactory?

Comment: could you post your jsonData ? it might have a blank character at the beginning.